# Wordpress new post

Tags: wordpress, automation

on a default wordpress installation, what actually happens when you click publish?

I know there's a new entry added to the posts table, but what else happens - Is there anything else updated such as tables, automatically telling search engines about them, updating sitemaps etc?

Sorry if this is the wrong sort of question to ask!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[save_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post) action is triggered whenever a post is created or updated, it means that any code inside core, themes, or plugins that is hooked with that action is launched.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you have google XML sitemap, a new entry makes changes in your sitemap xml file and during google bot's next visit, your xml file automatically tells google about the new post you added. Something like this.